# Why masechet "Beitza" and not masechet Yom Tov?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, names, yom-tov, tractate-beitza

Why do we call it masechet Beitza now, and not masechet Yom Tov, as was apparently once common? Unlike the parshiot, which are named after their first words, masechtot are all named after topics, except Beitza. This is particularly odd considering that today, many people actually call it "Bei'a" to avoid a word not appropriate for mixed company. So why not just call it "Yom Tov"?

Comment: What we call "Moed Kattan" was commonly called "Mashkin" way back when.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks. Interestingly this is what it says on Wikipedia:  רוב הראשונים והגאונים קוראים לה מסכת משקין על פי המילה הראשונה של המסכת**[דרוש מקור] But I did see some other hits and HebrewBooks results calling it that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the beginning of Rabbenu Chananel on Masseches Beitzah, where he - or whomever copied the manuscript the printed text is based on - began it with the following rhyming ditty:

אתחיל מסכת ביצה
בעזרת גדול העיצה

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because "Yom Tov" just sounds like too generic a name? There are, after all, several other masechtos that discuss, and/or are named for, specific Yamim Tovim.

Comment: what about masechet Taharot? that could be anything! I was thinking there must be some historical reason for the shift, since many Rishonim definitely called it Y"T.

Comment: True, but then (quite aside from the fact that fewer people are familiar with Seder Taharos than with Seder Moed), none of the masechtos of Taharos are named for specific pure items; they're named either for things that can be tamei or tahor (Kelim, Yadayim, etc.) or for things that are indeed tamei (Negaim, Zavim, etc.). Whereas in Moed, for example, you've got Rosh Hashanah, which is named for a specific Yom Tov.